# ¿Como verificar que el QLineEdit esta vacio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Como hago para saber que el lineEdit no este vacio antes de realizar x acción?

Algo como:

```py
if(lineEdit vacio):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

¿Como pregunto si esta vacio? Es decir, ¿que no tiene contenido?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que verificar que el texto que provee el QLineEdit este vacio:

```py
if not lineEdit.text():
   print("El QLineEdit esta vacio")
```